# undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My app successfully creates rows for a table every time a user submits some stats. Now I want to provide a delete button to be able to delete some rows.

When I click the delete button I get the error:

```
undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
```

Seems like either rails doesn't understand the destroy method in this case for whatever reason, or rails doesn't see anything to destroy, hence the nil:NilClass.

My first question is in identifying which is the case, if either of those.

My second question is fixing it :D

Here's my show.html:

```
<% provide(:title, "Log" ) %>
<% provide(:heading, "Your Progress Log") %>

<div class="row">  
  <div class="span8">
    <% if @user.status_update.any? %>
      <h3>Status Updates (<%= @user.status_update.count %>)</h3>    
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Entry Date</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>BF %</th>
            <th>LBM</th>
            <th>Fat</th>
            <th>Weight Change</th>
            <th>BF % Change</th>
            <th>Fat Change</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody class = "status updates">
          <%= render @status_updates %>
      </tbody>        
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The "<%= render @status_updates %>" calls the _status_update partial.

```
 <tr>
 .
 .
 .
 . 
 <% if current_user==(status_update.user) %> 
 <td>
       <%= link_to "delete", status_update, method: :delete %>

 </td>
 <%  end  %>         

</tr>
```

And then finally, here is the StatusUpdateController

```
def destroy
    @status_update.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

Here are the parameters on the error page:

```
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"w9eYIUEd2taghvzlo7p3uw0vdOZIVsZ1zYIBxgfBymw=",
 "id"=>"106"}
```

Comment: @status_update is not defined in your controller. You need to access it via parameters (params[:id]) or if using resources, resource.destroy. Check your rake routes to be sure what params to use.

Comment: Are you assigning `@status_update` in a `before_filter` for your destroy method? If not, that's where your problem is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you are not showing any code (filters or so) that could assign `@status_update`, I assume there is none. So, the instance variable `@status_update` in your in your `destroy` method is  not set. You need to query the class with the object's ID.

Rewrite your destroy method as follows:

```
def destroy
    @status_update = StatusUpdate.find(params[:id])
    if @status_update.present?
      @status_update.destroy
    end
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

Note: Replace the classname `StatusUpdate` with your actual class name.

Comment: I see. I'm following a tutorial for a different project and there were some bits of code I didn't understand that I now see have this exact purpose. 

It's got a private function called "correct user" that assigns the @status_update instance to an object id. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how & when that method is called?

Comment: In the before filter. I put:

before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy

And then under private I have :

 private

    def correct_user
      @status_update = current_user.status_update.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @status_update.nil?
    end

Comment: Try putting `:destroy` in an array like `before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:destroy]`.